# «Живая нить» — метафора или эпитет?

Tags: фразеология, общие-вопросы, тропы, метафора

Какое здесь средство выразительности?

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить, что перед нами  устойчивая развернутая метафора, которая состоит из двух частей. Возможные сочетания: ***живая нить времен/традиций/поколений.***

1. **Метафора** (от греч. mεταφορα  «перенесение» ) – вид тропа, предполагающий перенос наименования с одной реалии на другую на основе **сходства** признаков. Метафору также называют **скрытым сравнением.**

К примеру, сочетание ***нить времен*** – это метафора, построенная на сравнении:  нить и время мыслятся как нечто **непрерывное.**

2. Определение ***живой*** является эпитетом. **Эпитет** (от др.-греч. ἐπίθετον «приложенное») – вид тропа, красочное определение,  которое придает речи выразительность и образность.  Эпитет, в отличие от обычного определения, также метафоричен – он  подчеркивает в предмете одно свойство (*гордый конь*) или переносит на него свойства другого предмета (**живой след**).

В нашем случае ***живая нить времен*** – это связь, передаваемая через потомков,  через живых людей.

Для справок: **троп** (от греч. tropos — поворот, оборот, оборот речи) —  понятие поэтики и стилистики, обозначающее такие обороты (образы), которые основаны на употреблении слова (или сочетания слов) в переносном значении и используются для усиления изобразительности и выразительности речи.